# awk print ' char

Tags: shell, awk, quoting

I want to print:

```
cat file.log | awk '{print nir's $1}'
```

output should be:

```
nir's aaa
nir's bbb
nir's abc
nir's dbc
```

The problem is with the `'` in `nir's`.

I also tried:

```
cat file.log | awk '{print nir\'s $1}'
cat file.log | awk '{print nir''s $1}'
cat file.log | awk '{print nir'''s $1}'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to quote the single quote to protect it from the shell. That means instead of

```
$ cat file.log | awk '{print nir's $1}'
```

you have to write something like

```
$ awk '{print "nir'"'"'s",$1}' file.log
```

Comment: Useless use of `cat`. You don't need to cat the file `file.log` to `awk`. The command `awk` can deal with the filename directly.

Comment: @slm Not to mention that it's not merely an issue of semantics, some optimisations may not be able to be applied when reading from a stream vs. reading from a file.

Comment: @slm, you are right. I've removed one useless use in my answer - the first one is quoted from the question.

Answer (score 8):

There are two problems here:

1. You can't pass `'` within `'`, which you are also using to quote the awk syntax. You need to leave the quoting first;
2. You need to quote strings in awk.

It seems like this is what you want:

```
awk '{print "nir'\''s " $1}'
```

Answer (score 5):

This should work:

```
cat file.log | awk '{print "nir\047s " $1}'
```